# Key doesn't Work Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: keyboard, 15.10

i can't type loWercase "W". Even on virtual keyboard. Xev reads input:

```
FocusOut event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusIn event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
keys:  2   0   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
root 0x2c0, subw 0x3000002, time 1663198, (33,24), root:(98,76),
state 0x10, keycode 25 (keysym 0x77, w), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (77) "w"
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Same on russian layout - i can't type loWercase "Ц".
also - any hotkeys are Working (Ctrl+W in Firefox, for example)

HoW one could fix it?

Update: in terminal (ctrl+alt+f1) loWercase W Works. So, problem is X11 or something

Comment: Maybe it's a hardware problem? Open your keyboard and check.

Comment: it isn't, becouse i can type uppercase W Without any problem. And xev can read loWercase input also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In shortcut manager w (by not obvious for me circumstaces) was mapped as shortcut. I deleted it. All works.